# connect to windows vpn (peap) from linux

Tags: windows, linux, vpn, tls, peap

Our admin just changed the vpn stuff to something different and I'd like to know how to connect to the windows vpn from a linux (debian testing) box.

1. a **certificate file** (in `p7b` format, which I was able to convert to `pem`, which supposedly helps...)
2. the **name for a CA** that I'm supposed to trust and
3. a **server name** which I'm supposed to connect to (that does not resolve to an IP address when looking it up from the internet, but I still have the **IP address** I used with the old VPN installation and I think it is still the one to connect to)

The shear amount of acronyms you encounter when trying to figure this out is just amazing (eap-tls? eap-peap? eap-ttls? ???), and I had hopes that the patch at http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/ppp/doc.html could help me. But it seems like I need at least all the following:

```
  - Client certificate file 
    The file containing the certificate chain for the 
    client in PEM format
  - CA certificate file
    The file containing the trusted CA certificates in PEM
    format.
  - Client private key file
    The file containing the client private key in PEM format.
```

The windows guys only need that one file in order to set things up. So I'm not sure whether this is a dead end or how I'm supposed to get those files.

Here are the hopefully crucial bits of the converted-to-pem certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    ...
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
    ...
        X509v3 extensions:
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2: 
                ...C.A
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Non Repudiation, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Does anyone know how to connect to this Windows VPN?**

Comment: Windows supports several different VPN technologies.  You need to start by determining which one is being used.

Comment: I wrote what I know and what I think was sufficient for the Windows guys who successfully connected: PEAP. Is there more I need to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

> **Get your sysadmin to set up / open up ssh**

Works like a charm for me, *installation* was easy!

**ssh** makes **tunneling** straightforward in case you want to do RDP etc.